# Scrolling issues with TRichEdit in Delphi

Tags: delphi, richedit

I am adding lines to a TRichEdit how do I keep focus on the line that has just been added?

```
For Idx := 1 to 1000 do
   RichEdit.Lines.add(IntToStr(Idx));
```

EDIT

I just what the bottom line of the richedit to show what was just added and all the other lines to scroll up

Comment: I think "focus" is usually used for controls.  Do you mean that you want to select the text that was just added (will result in pasting-over with the next operation), keep the insertion point on the last-added line (that will result in pasting one very long line) or perhaps you just mean you want to scroll to the bottom of the richedit?

Comment: See also this answer: [Scrolling RichEdit without it having focus](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9757314/576719).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work, if you just want to scroll to the end of the richedit:

```
For Idx := 1 to 1000 do
begin
  RichEdit.Lines.add(IntToStr(Idx));
  RichEdit.SelStart := RichEdit.GetTextLen;
  SendMessage(RichEdit.handle, EM_SCROLLCARET,0,0);
end;
```

If this is not what you wanted, please see my comment above and clarify your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

option 1) set the cursor when the loop finish

```
For Idx := 1 to 1000 do
   RichEdit.Lines.add(IntToStr(Idx));

RichEdit.SetFocus;
RichEdit.SelStart := RichEdit.Perform(EM_LINEINDEX, RichEdit.Lines.Count-1, 0) ;
```

option 2) set the cursor while the loop is executing

```
For Idx := 1 to 1000 do
Begin
RichEdit.Lines.add(IntToStr(Idx));
RichEdit.SetFocus;
End;

RichEdit.SelStart := RichEdit.Perform(EM_LINEINDEX, RichEdit.Lines.Count-1, 0) ;
```

Bye.